# using getText() with a double

Tags: java, swing, parsing, double, jtextfield

I am trying to get the content of a `JTextField` and I am setting the contents to a double variable.

However I think I need an alternative as I am unable to use `getText()` as it is only for string variables?

```
numbers = webpage.getText();
```

returns the error incompatible types?

Comment: `and I am setting the contents to a double variable.` - please how, this is possible with JFormattedTextField, for JTextField required extra effort

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use

```
numbers = Double.parseDouble(webpage.getText());
```

that will convert the string into a double for you.

Answer (score 4):

> returns the error incompatible types?

This is because `JTextField.getText()` returns a string not a double.

You should convert your string into a double to be able to assign it to your `numbers` variable.
The following should solve your problem:

```
try{
  numbers = Double.parseDouble(webpage.getText());
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){
 // The user entered an invalid number, report the error
}
```